# What's wrong with my Git alias

Tags: git, alias

I want an alias for git to delete a branch both from local and remote repositories. So, I've created one in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    erase = !"git push origin :$1 && git branch -D $1"
```

It works as expected, deletes branch from origin and local but in console I see extra line (`error: branch 'profile_endpoints' not found.`):

```
┌[madhead@MADHEAD-LAPTOP:/c/projects/b developing]
└─$ git erase profile_endpoints
To git@github.com:a/b.git
 - [deleted]         profile_endpoints
Deleted branch profile_endpoints (was abcdef0).
error: branch 'profile_endpoints' not found.
```

I'm using `git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0` and `git bash` on Windows 7.

What am I missing?

Comment: The branch existed remotely as well as locally? How about after you run the command?

Comment: The branch of course existed both in local and remote repos. After erase it was deleted. By extra line shows that git tried to do something strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you run a git alias, git tacks on the arguments at the end of the string.  Try, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    showme = !echo git push origin :$1 && echo git branch -D $1
```

Then run:

```
$ git showme profile_endpoints
git push origin :profile_endpoints
git branch -D profile_endpoints profile_endpoints
```

There are various workarounds.  One trivial one is to assume that this will be given one argument that will be appended, so:

```
[alias]
    showme = !echo git push origin :$1 && echo git branch -D
```

However, this version increases the danger of misuse:

```
$ git showme some oops thing
git push origin :some
git branch -D some oops thing
```

Another standard trick is to define a shell function so that all the tacked-on arguments are passed:

```
[alias]
    showme = !"f() { case $# in 1) echo ok, $1;; *) echo usage;; esac; }; f"

$ git showme some oops thing
usage
$ git showme one
ok, one
```

One that's a little bit iffier is to use a dummy "absorb extra arguments" command:

```
[alias]
    showme = !"echo first arg is $1 and others are ignored; :"

$ git showme one two three
first arg is one and others are ignored
```

My own personal rule is to switch to a "real" shell script as soon as the alias gets complicated. :-)